# Vaadin 22 with Spring MVC and Spring Security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, vaadin, vaadin22

I am trying to get a basic Vaadin22 app running with Spring MVC and Spring Security. The [vaadin docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/v22/flow/integrations/spring/view-based-access-control) seem to allude that this is possible,

> If an application is based on Spring Boot, this mechanism can be enabled by using a set of annotations and with minimum Spring Security configurations. However, it is also possible to use it in Vaadin Spring applications that are not based on Spring Boot, with some extra configurations.

I have started with [skeleton-starter-flow v22](https://github.com/vaadin/skeleton-starter-flow/tree/v22), forked to [here](https://github.com/smillied/skeleton-starter-flow) and added basic Spring integration (see [here](https://github.com/smillied/skeleton-starter-flow/commit/b30c2ed4924cdd9db709da0b2739dd9395408ebe)). I have then attempted to add Spring Security.

I initially extended Vaadin's VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (see [here](https://github.com/smillied/skeleton-starter-flow/commit/cd5781b06b75954bb291c3b867270d6642a86cc2)), but when I run the app it fails because there are missing autowired dependencies.

Next, I forced some component scanning to detect the missing dependencies (see [here](https://github.com/smillied/skeleton-starter-flow/commit/38345e8b409c572b7b6436c10e55a3fb497e024c)), but now there is a ClassNotFoundException because there is a dependency on the Spring Boot class, ServletRegistrationBean

Finally, I abandoned Vaadin's VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and instead extended Spring's WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (see [here](https://github.com/smillied/skeleton-starter-flow/commit/ec535f25b5e215291dcbd32ab92a965d1db720c7)). Now the app runs, but I am not seeing the default login screen that Spring is supposed to provide by default.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Note: The app can be run using,

```
mvn jetty:run
```

Comment: Maybe start from a project that already has security enabled: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-crm-tutorial

Comment: Thanks @Eisenknurr ... I need to use Spring MVC and so was avoiding Spring Boot solutions. Thankfully, I managed to solve it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that Vaadin's VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is intended for use with Spring Boot (which I'm trying to avoid). In order to get basic Spring Security working, I extended Spring's WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter instead, but I was missing an implementation of Spring's AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer which registers the appropriate security filter. See [here](https://github.com/smillied/skeleton-starter-flow/commit/83f35988c1df4f709199e866f5b1c461d1f4a4af) for the working solution.

The problem with this, is that I will not get Vaadin's [View-Based Access Control](https://vaadin.com/docs/v22/flow/integrations/spring/view-based-access-control). In order to get this, I will need to start using/migrating functionality from VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.